# Connotations of "Is there any" vs "Are there any"

Tags: grammar

For countable nouns, both "Is there any  `x`?" and "Are there any `x`?" are [grammatical](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21347/8278) and [correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/17549/8278).

But what **nuance** / **connotation** differences are there between them?

For example, if we're [searching for a Chrome plugin to do *something*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20108/356), what's the connotation difference between:

> **Is** there any Chrome **plugin** to do this?

vs:

> **Are** there any Chrome **plugins** to do this?

Related threads (which only increases the confusion):

- https://www.englishforums.com/English/IsThereAnyVsAreThereAny/vdpvg/post.htm#353324
- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113005/8278

Comment: Looking at the related threads, it does seem rather complex. Could it be, though, that _any_ just stands, in the singular case, for "a", and for "some" in the plural case? "Is there a Chrome plugin?"; "Are there some Chrome plugins?"

Comment: If you expect there might only be one, you can use *"is there any"*. If you expect there to be many, you should use *"are there any"*. For instance, you would say *"are there any apples in this store?"* and *"is there any country that claims this island?"*

Comment: @PeterShor: It does. Unless perhaps you'd spent hours searching for apples and found none in the store, Then you might, in frustration, exclaim "Is there _any_ apple in this store!" Might you?

Comment: @Margana: you might.

Comment: @PeterShor:   I might exclaim "Is there _any_ meaning in my last comment now you've edited what I was replying to". : )

Comment: To me, the natural forms are _Is there a_ and _Are there any_. The form _Is there any_ is unnatural, and suggests that I am expecting the answer "No".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With "is there any" it implies to me that the speaker is asking for one solution; a "magic bullet" type of Chrome plugin to use your example. They're asking for a particular solution; perhaps the "best" one.

With "are there any" it implies that the speaker is asking a more open-ended question and not looking for a one-size-fits-all solution, but will evaluate the suggestions.